# Get a single value prediction from a 2-class softmax output

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a binary classification problem but with a `Dense(2, activation='softmax')` layer at the end. So I get predictions like `[0.2, 0.8]` or `[1.0, 0.0]` for instance. Am I calculating a resulting single-value-prediction correctly?

`single_value_prediction = predictions[predicted_class] if predictions[1] > predictions[0] else 1 - predictions[predicted_class]`

So `[0.2, 0.8]` would result in `0.8` and `[1.0, 0.0]` in `0.0`?

Thanks!

Comment: So, you're getting the list, and sorting it to output the class with highest softmax score right?

Comment: If you have Binary classification problem , you can directly use single value of output layer Dense(1, activation='softmax'), why are you interested in doing seperately

Comment: What if it returns both as 0.5 you need a threshold in such situations

Answer (score 1):

After getting the predictions using:

```
preds = model.predict(test_data)
```

the `preds` array would have a shape of `(n_samples, 2)`. Now to find the predicted class you can easily use `np.argmax()`:

```
preds_classes = np.argmax(preds, axis=-1)
```

Alternatively, if your model is a Sequential model, i.e. `keras.models.Sequential`, (and not a model defined using functional API, i.e. `keras.model.Model`) you can use `predict_classes()` method directly:

```
preds_classes = model.predict_classes(test_data)
```

If you would like to find the probability of predicted class (i.e. class with the highest probability) then you can use `np.max()`:

```
preds_class_prob = np.max(preds, axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want "[0.2, 0.8] would result in 0.8 and [1.0, 0.0] in 0.0", you could try `prediction = model.predict(data)[:, 1]`.

If you want to turn the probabilities into classes at the same time, try `prediction = model.predict(data)[:, 1] > 0.5`. Or use np.argmax, as @today suggested.